# Align a Hbox to the bottom center inside a StakePanel

Tags: javafx

I'm learning Javafx layouts and I would like to obtain the following result:

[image]

HBox in the bottom center fo a Pane I have tried with the following code but I'm not able to do that

Can you please explain what I'm doing wrong? and How to achieve that?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class TestLayout extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        initUI(stage);
    }

    private void initUI(Stage stage) {
        Scene scene =null;
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFFAAA;");
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #AAFAAA;");
        hbox.prefWidthProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(4));
        hbox.prefHeightProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().divide(10));

        pane.getChildren().add(hbox);

        scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);
        pane.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
        pane.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());

        stage.setTitle("Test");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


}

class AppLauncherTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestLayout.main(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would Use a `VBox` or `BorderPane` as the root node. In this example, I use a `VBox`. I am assuming more nodes will go into this so I used a `StackPane` as the top node. This may need to be changed out or some other `Pane` may need to be added to this. That depends on what you are trying to do with the end product. For the bottom, I used an `HBox` and I set it's `Margins`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {        
        StackPane subRootTop = new StackPane();     
        VBox.setVgrow(subRootTop, Priority.ALWAYS); 
        //subRootTop.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow;");

        HBox subRootBotton = new HBox();
        VBox.setVgrow(subRootBotton, Priority.ALWAYS);      
        subRootBotton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green;");
        subRootBotton.setMaxHeight(150);
        VBox.setMargin(subRootBotton, new Insets(40, 40, 40, 40));

        VBox root = new VBox(subRootTop, subRootBotton);
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);;

        stage.setTitle("Test");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The binding of the `StackPane` is not size shouldn't be done. The scene automatically resizes its root to fill the whole area available. Assuming you want relative sizes, using `StackPane` is not really a good choice.

If you want the child to have a fixed distance to left right and bottom of the `StackPane`, you can do so specifying margins and alignment. Make sure the child does not grow to fit the parent though by setting the `maxHeight` to use the preferred height:

```
private void initUI(Stage stage) {
    HBox hbox = new HBox();
    hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFFAAA;");
    hbox.setMaxHeight(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);

    // could be calculated based on children instead of assigning
    // an absolute value
    hbox.setPrefHeight(30);

    StackPane.setAlignment(hbox, Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
    StackPane.setMargin(hbox, new Insets(20));

    StackPane pane = new StackPane(hbox);
    pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #AAFAAA;");

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 600, 600);

    stage.setTitle("Test");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: I have tried to follow you suggestion (you can find an UPDATE section in my question), but I don't understand why "hbox.setMaxHeight" works for Height but hbox.setMaxWidth doesn't work for width, can you please explain that?

Comment: @navy1978 `setMaxWidth` does not occur at all in your code snippets. `setMaxSize` doesn't appear either...

Comment: sorry you are right I deleted that part, another question: Is there a way to listen to a resize event of a pane instead of doing it separately one for width and another for height: "stage.widthProperty().addListener" and "stage.eightProperty().addListener" ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use an `AnchorPane` as a base layout instead of the `StacKPane`. I made a small exmaple how it would look like. Of cause you could keep the `StackPane` as the base layout and just put the `AnchorPane` with the `HBox` onto it, but you should definitly use an `AnchorPane` for your plan.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private void initUI(Stage stage) {

        // Create an anchor pane as base layout and set a color:
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #FFFAAA;");

        // Create a second container and set a minimum height and a color;
        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setMinHeight(100d);
        hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #AAFAAA;");

        // Give the child container a fixed location:
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(hbox, 50d);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(hbox, 75d);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(hbox, 75d);

        // Add the horizontal box to the base anchor pane:
        root.getChildren().add(hbox);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 600));
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        initUI(stage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Preview:

[image: Preview]